# What is causing my EXC_BAD_ACCESS? (iPhone SDK)

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

```
- (IBAction)startSignin:(id)sender {
    Login *aview = [[Login alloc] init];
    aview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:aview animated:YES];

    [_window addSubview:aview.view];
    [aview release];
}
```

What is causing my EXC BAD ACCESS?

Every time it loads Login, It crashes whenever i press a button or something on that page.

```
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc25a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f16313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d7aef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d7ae6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x000c6709 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 295
    5   UIKit                               0x000c4134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x000c400e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    7   UIKit                               0x00037d42 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 51
    8   Test                           0x00001b3c -[TestAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 220
    9   UIKit                               0x00014c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    10  UIKit                               0x00016d88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    11  UIKit                               0x00021617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    12  UIKit                               0x00019abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x0001ef2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffb992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00da3944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d03cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  UIKit                               0x000167d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    21  UIKit                               0x00022c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  Test                           0x00001a29 main + 121
    23  Test                           0x000019a5 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from your crash?

Comment: argc int 1
argv char ** 0xbffff664
pool NSAutoreleasePool * 0x4b53d60
retVal int -1073744276       -     Is this it?

Comment: I'm not sure i know where to find the stack trace...

Comment: It's in the debugger view.  It will be the nested series of calls that led to your crash.

Answer (score 2):

This is frequently caused by accessing an object after it is released.  This is a good point to familiarize yourself with the debugger, too.  Set a break point on the first line of the button action method, and step through it to find out which line is bad.

This time, i suspect it is your call to `addSubview:`, the `presentModal…` will take care of presenting the view.

Comment: Yes, It wouldn't present the view so i had to addSubView

Comment: if presentModal… did not show anything i'd suspect view == nil, either it's not connected in the nib file or it's not created by `loadView` (however you're planning on doing that)

Comment: have you confirmed that view==nil?